# How to map <c-leader> in vim?

Tags: vim, keymapping

I would like to map ctrl+leader key. Is it possible?

Tried: `:nnoremap <c-leader> :CtrlP<CR>`

And it does not work.

(ctrlp bindings conflict with yankring bindings)

Comment: +1 for referencing [ctrlp plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3736), which I didn't know and seems very useful.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`<Leader>` is a special key notation in Vim; as such, it cannot be combined with modifiers such as `C-`. Assuming the default setting for it (i.e. `\`), you can use this:

```
nnoremap <c-\> :CtrlP<CR>
```

Comment: For a moment thought it would screw up leader binding - but no... Works perfectly. \ is still a leader and c-\ pops up ctrlp. tyvm :)

Answer (score 6):

There are two issues, here:

1. You didn't read CtrlP's documentation where you would have found this:

   ```
   Use this option to change the mapping to invoke CtrlP in Normal mode:
       let g:ctrlp_map = '<c-p>'
   ```
2. `<leader>` is supposed to be a cross-platform alternative to using the common modifier keys (Alt, Ctrl, Shift, Cmd) in mappings.

   Normally, you would use `<leader>` in place of `<Ctrl>` as in:

   ```
   nnoremap <leader>p :CtrlP<CR>
   ```

This line in your `~/.vimrc` will probably solve your problem:

```
let g:crtlp_map='<F11>'
```

Though it won't help much here are my mappings for CtrlP:

```
nnoremap <leader>f :CtrlP<CR>
nnoremap <leader>b :CtrlPBuffer<CR>
nnoremap <leader>m :CtrlPMRUFiles<CR>
nnoremap <leader>t :CtrlPTag<CR>
```

Comment: Did read it. Don't get what second issue is. Won't solve because don't want it to be mapped on F11.

Comment: `<F11>` is an example, you can map it to whatever you want/is available. The second issue is explained well by Ingo: `<leader>` is a special key which can't be combined with a modifier. I just provided an example of proper usage.

Answer (score -1):

For example to map leader key to space try this ...

`let mapleader=" "`